# Select bigger data From a table

Tags: mysql, database

```
borrow_id borrower_id book_id borrow_date expected_return_date
        1          19       6 0000-00-00  0000-00-00
        2           1      10 0000-00-00  0000-00-00
        3          20       1 0000-00-00  0000-00-00
        4          18       3 2016-04-30  2016-05-02
        5          19       8 2016-04-30  2016-05-03
        6          21       7 2016-04-30  2016-05-03
        7          22      14 2016-01-05  0000-00-00
        8          13       1 2016-05-02  2016-06-04
        9          18       3 2016-06-02  2016-05-26
       12          23      14 2016-06-02  2016-05-03
       13           1       5 2016-05-02  0000-00-00
       14          23       1 2016-05-02  2016-05-03
```

This is my table. For same values of borrower_id column I want one borrow_id which is bigger of all. for example there are borrower_id 19 two times.I want borrow_id 5 row not borrow_id 1 row as 5>1.

What will be the query for that?

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a where in with a subselect grop by

```
 select * from my_table 
 where (borrow_id, borrower_id)  in  (select max(borrow_id), borrower_id 
       from my_table group by borrower_id);
```

Comment: Will grouping by borrower_id and MAX(borrow_id) would work? I'm asking because i'm not sure

Comment: Something like `SELECT borrow_id, MAX(borrower_id) FROM borrow GROUP BY borrow_id`? I'm having a blackout

Comment: @AlonEitan  well  your select with group by borrow_id return tha same value of the table without group by  because borrow_id is the id of the table and then there is nothing to group .. for this doing the inverse i can obtain the more high id with the borrower_id

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from borrow where borrow_id =
  (select max(borrow_id) from borrow where borrower_id=19)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP was after 19 specifically.